# Export Distribution Groups-How do I output one line per member?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that gives me the data I need, except I'm having trouble changing it so that it lists a separate line for every member instead of listing all members in one cell. Any ideas?

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {(GroupCategory -eq "Distribution")} -Properties Name,
    Description, Location, Department, Mail, Company, Proxyaddresses, Members | 
Select-Object Name, Description, Location, Department, Mail, Company,
    @{n= "ProxyAddresses"; E = {$_.ProxyAddresses -join "; " | 
Where-Object {"ProxyAddresses -like '*'"}}}, 
    @{n='Members';e={(get-adgroupmember $_.name).name -join "; "}} |
Sort-object Name | 
Export-CSV C:\Temp\DistributionGroups.CSV -notypeinformation
```

current output:

[image: current output]

desired output:

[image: desired output]

Comment: [1] please, fix your code formatting. [*grin*] [2] please, DO NOT post images of code/errors/sample-data. why? >>> Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in the CSV represents an object. If you want each member to be on its own row, then you must output an object that contains just one member.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'" -Properties Name,Description,Location,Department,Mail,Company,Proxyaddresses | Foreach-Object {
    $Members = Get-ADGroupMember $_.SamAccountName
    if (-not $Members) {
        $Members = "" | Select-Object Name # For when there are no group members
    } 
    $ProxyAddresses = ($_.ProxyAddresses | where {$_}) -join '; '
    foreach ($Member in $Members) {
        $_ | Select-Object Name,Description,Location,Department,Mail,Company,@{n= "ProxyAddresses"; E = { $ProxyAddresses} }, @{n='Members';e={$Member.Name}}
    }
} | Sort-object Name | Export-CSV C:\Temp\DistributionGroups.CSV -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for,except I am getting an error on a few:

Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Region One Sales' under:
'DC=contoso,DC=com'.
At line:2 char:16
+     $Members = Get-ADGroupMember $_.Name
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Region One Sales:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,M   icrosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: I updated it to use samaccountname instead of name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the information needed as you stated, the following should work to get your desired output. I have not tested this code but it should work, and you can probably bunch this all up into a single command. I just don't like to do that while testing things. It makes it too hard to figure out where the problem lies.

```
$adGroupQuery = Get-ADGroup -Filter { (GroupCategory -eq "Distribution") } `
-Properties Name,Description,Location,Department,Mail,Company,Proxyaddresses,Members | 
Select-Object Name,Description,Location,Department,Mail,Company, 
@{n= "ProxyAddresses"; E = { $_.ProxyAddresses -join "; " | Where-Object { "ProxyAddresses -like '*'" } } },
@{n='Members';e={(get-adgroupmember $_.name).name -join "; "}}

$adGroup = @()

foreach ($group in $adGroupQuery)
{
    foreach ($item in $group.Members.Split(';'))
    {
        $adGroup += [psobject]@{
            name = $group.name
            description = $group.description
            location = $group.location
            department = $group.department
            mail = $group.mail
            company = $group.company
            ProxyAddresses = $group.ProxyAddresses
            members = $item
        }
    }  
}



$adGroup | Sort-object Name | Export-CSV C:\Temp\DistributionGroups.CSV -notypeinformation
```